# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C47C8528-950A-4D52-802C-AED89CD9042B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

i am using third party DLL call Interop.flixengine_com.dll.
although i ma registerd it using Resam for GAC and it is refring from GAC.

but i cant not create object of it giving above damn error.pls help.

Answer (score 4):

That interop.X.dll is actually a wrapper around some other, unmanaged DLL that's called something like fixengine_com.dll - you need to deploy the latter on the machine where your code is running - specifically you need to copy that DLL and all its dependencies and run regsvr32 to register it with COM. That unmanaged DLL contains the COM server - actual code that will serve your requests and the interop.X.dll is only a wrapper to route calls from your managed code into that unmanaged COM server.